# How to pass an array of strings in a Windows Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the command below in as a Windows Batch File and it will run just fine with one parameter.

```
start /d "C:\TestRunner\bin\Release" Runner.exe   "99F46289-3B9D-4D21-AE53-E8AD9F502BE2"
```

I would like to send it an array of strings like the following

```
//args = new[] { "99F46289-3B9D-4D21-AE53-E8AD9F502BE2", "1" };
```

How would I format the command to run above with a string array?

Comment: The `cmd.exe` batch language has no concept of arrays, it can only pass string arguments to other programs. It is up to each target program to interpret these strings, so you need to consult the documentation for `Runner.exe` to learn if and how arrays can be passed; sometimes this just means that the array elements must be passed as individual arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may modify the exe file, this is an example.
The c# program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  foreach (string arg in args)
       Console.WriteLine("Argument: " + arg);

  Console.WriteLine("End");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Command to launch:

```
start ConsoleApp3.exe par01 par02 par03 par04
```

And the output:

```
Argument: par01
Argument: par02
Argument: par03
Argument: par04
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are nothing more than a way to seperate memory by indexes and cmd.exe can do that just fine with a little creativity. You should really clarify more what you want to do here. Here is how you can do an array from cmd.exe

```
@echo off
set my_string_array="item1" "0" "item2" "1" "item3" "3"
call :process_array %my_string_array%
goto :EOF

:process_array
if "%~1"=="" goto :EOF
echo Current array %~1=%~2
shift && shift
goto :process_array
```

Comment: I was just going to post this as a comment but I cant get the formatting to work that way.